# Iterator of if-functions return errors

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error, code-formatting

I have just started on a coding project that can encode messages. When trying to use if and elif functions, repl.it is returning an error, no matter what I try to end the if functions with.

Code:

```
    ConvertString = input("Enter a string: ")
    StringList = list(ConvertString)
    print (StringList)
    for x in list(range(len(StringList))
      if StringList[x] == "a":
        print("Letter found: a")
      elif StringList[x] == "b"
        print("Letter found: b")
      elif StringList[x] == "c"
        print("Letter found: c")
      elif StringList[x] == "d"
        print("Letter found: d")
      elif StringList[x] == "e"
        print("Letter found: e")
      elif StringList[x] == "f"
        print("Letter found: f")
      x += 1
```

Comment: Could you provide an error message that pops up in your terminal?

Comment: On this link: https://focusedfrontprocessor.johnlang2015.repl.run/

Comment: Hi John, you're missing colons after the `elif` expressions. That will be giving you `syntax error: invalid syntax`.

Comment: I just added the colons: The error is saying that the issue is on line 5, and the colon is incorrect. Line 5 from the top, or the (if StringList[x] == "a":)

Comment: Please [edit] all relevant information into the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Pythons for loops are defined as `for x in y:`. You forgot about the `:`. The colons are also needed after `ifs` or `elifs` or `elses`

Also, you don't have to convert a `range()` into a list. `range()` in Python3 returns a generator, which you can safely iterate on (in Python2 you would have to use `xrange`).

Also, you don't have to increment `x` as it's being incremented by Pythons `for` loop.

Then, don't use C-like loops. You don't have to operate on the indexes. It's better to write more pythonic code, by using Pythons for loop like other languages `foreach`:

```
ConvertString = input("Enter a string: ")
StringList = list(ConvertString)
print (StringList)
for x in StringList:
  if x == "a":
    print("Letter found: a")
  elif x == "b":
    print("Letter found: b")
  elif x == "c":
    print("Letter found: c")
  elif x == "d":
    print("Letter found: d")
  elif x == "e":
    print("Letter found: e")
  elif x == "f":
    print("Letter found: f")
```

And the last one, if you only care about `a-f` letters, fine, you could write a code like this. But it would be better to check if the letter is `>= a` or `<= f`. But if you want to check the whole alphabet, it's better to write it like this:

```
ConvertString = input("Enter a string: ")
StringList = list(ConvertString)
print (StringList)
for x in StringList:
  print(f"Letter found: {x}")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm a bit rusty on python as I've been working in C#. If I'm converting each letter to a number, could I use a list and then use x to pull the number from said list?

Comment: Yes, and, like in C#, it doesn't have to be `x`. You can use whatever name you want to